# How to estimate the I/O operations performed by MySQL queries?

Tags: mysql

On Amazon's RDS, you pay about $0.10 per 1 million I/O requests. I've noticed a very high number (in hundreds of thousands) of I/O requests for a very low traffic database. On seeing this, I did some further research, and found this question which describes that for a 6,000 user website, he was generating 800 million I/O requests a month, which would cost him about $80 / month.

Therefore, I want to know in advance how many I/O operations a MySQL query would generate, and how to optimize / minimize them. Is there any way to estimate how many I/O operations a query would perform, and any general rules I can follow to keep them as low as possible?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from comments on the question by [Raymond Nijland](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/27070/raymond-nijland)*</sub>

Use `EXPLAIN`. This way you can see if an query MAY need disk IO. You need to avoid in the column *extra* "Using temporary" or ""Using temporary; Using filesort (note the filesort is a misleading name: if the result set fits in memory, quicksort is run in memory)".

This is most likely to be caused by subqueries/unions/order by/group by/... If your result is big and a MyISAM disk-based temporary table is created, and you need to sort the result, you are sorting the result set based on IO reads and IO writes with quicksort algorithm.

In [Internal Temporary Table Use in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) you can read when MySQL needs to create a disk-based MyISAM table. Maybe you can use *avg_row_length * rows* (though note that the *rows* value from explain is not exact with InnoDB engine) to check if the result fits in the heap. See [SHOW TABLE STATUS Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html).

> In general is InnoDB or MyISAM better for avoiding I/O requests?

InnoDB will buffer table data and index data, whereas MyISAM only buffers index keys. An I/O to the table data is needed when explain column *extra* doesn't say "Using index".

If both are using indexes: With InnoDB, if the buffer is hot it can load data from memory. If indexes need to come from disk there a formula that you can use to calculate needed IO reads for selects, inserts, and updates. From [Estimating Query Performance](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/estimating-performance.html):

> For small tables, you can usually find a row in one disk seek (because the index is probably cached). For bigger tables, you can estimate that, using B-tree indexes, you need this many seeks to find a row:
>
> ```
> log(rows) / log(index_block_length / 3 * 2 / (index_length + data_pointer_length)) + 1
> ```

InnoDB indexes are larger because it stores data off the PRIMARY / UNIQUE key into an KEY index. This is faster and needs even less IO seeks but you can compress InnoDB data or indexes.